# Sync local react state with data from redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an `App` component which contains all the routes

App.jsx

```
import Editor from './Editor';

function App(props) {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/cms/post/edit/:postId" component={Editor} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
export default App;
```

I have an `Editor` component where user can edit a post. This component maps the data from redux store to local state as data needs to be manipulated locally.

Editor.jsx

```
// Usual Imports

class Editor extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: props.post ? props.post.title : '',
            content: props.post ? props.post.content : ''
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.post ? null : this.fetchPosts(this.props.match.params.postId);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    }

    updatePost(data) {
        // function to updatePost 
    }

    fetchPosts(id) {
        // function to fetch Posts
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <input type="text" name="title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <input type="text" name="content" value={this.state.content} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    post: state.posts[ownProps.match.params.postId] || false,
    ...ownProps
}),
mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    updatePost: data => dispatch(updatePost(data)),
    fetchPosts: params => dispatch(fetchPosts(params))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Editor);
```

Now my questions are

Initially, post data is available and `fetchPosts` is not called. However, if user refreshes the page then `post` becomes `false` and `fetchPosts` is called and `redux store` is updated.

1. **In which `lifecycle method` should I update the local react state with data from `props`**?

Possible solutions which I think could be

**A. Updating state in `componentWillReceiveProps`**

```
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            title: nextProps.post.title,
            content: nextProps.post.content
        });
    }
```

However, React docs discourages using `componentWillReceiveProps` as it might be invoked many times in React 16 and so on.

**B. Update state in `componentDidUpdate`**

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.post != prevProps.post) {
        this.setState({
            title: this.props.title,
            content: this.props.content
        });
    }
}
```

I am not sure about this as I think there might be hidden side effects of this approach.

C. **Not setting initial state and providing `value` to `input` tags via `props` i.e. `value={this.props.post.title}` and updating `state` via `onChange handlers`. However, when `value` is `undefined` then React will throw an `error`**.

D. **Newer `lifecycle methods` like `getDerivedStateFromProps`. Not too sure as React docs says it should be used in rare cases when state changes based on props over time**.

I need to maintain the state as current component is also used for creating a fresh post also.

Which approach would be the best? And if I am missing out on something then let me know! Thanks!

Comment: if you are already using redux then don't use state, just dispatch a action, update and read data from reducers.

Comment: @Abhishek But if I don't use state then how will I update as user changes the value?

Comment: by dispatching a redux actions. you should check out some redux examples.

Comment: In my opinion approach should be if you use redux then move every calculation inside redux other no need to use redux.  State works just fine in most cases